# Highcharts - insert point att specific position on xAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to insert an array of series into a highchart. The series may have different starting points on the xAxis and this causes an error for me with me current code.

This JavaScript show how I draw the chart:

```
var appLength = 0;
for (var app in last24Hours) {
  appLength = last24Hours[app].length;

  if (insertedSeries.indexOf(app) === -1) {
    stackedChart.addSeries({
      name: app,
      color: colors[colorCounter]
    });
  }
  appArray.push(last24Hours[app]);

  if (insertedSeries.indexOf(app) === -1) {
    insertedSeries.push(app);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < appArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < appArray[i].length; j++) {

     stackedChart.series[i].addPoint([CdnAnalyticsService.convertEPOCH(appArray[i][j].tValue), appArray[i][j].value], false, shift);

    latestInsertedTime = appArray[i][j].tValue;
  }
}
stackedChart.hideLoading();
stackedChart.redraw();
```

You can see in the picture here that the series named /00069-down1_qrac0 are inserted at the wrong place on the xAxis. Even though it should be almost on the far right on the axis, its drawn right from the beginning of the xAxis.

Any ideas of what im doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you show live example of your chart? Do you have any errors in your console (Developer Tools)?